# Having issue with writing text to specific Excel Cell using OpenXml

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, vba

**What I want to achieve is illustrated below:**

[image]

**The result and issue I've been having are illustrated below:**

This is the result file my code has generated and there supposed to have expected content.

[image]

Window prompt after the 'Yes' button has clicked.

[image]

My running code is given below:

**Main method:**

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    WriteExcelService writeExcelService = new WriteExcelService();
    Dictionary<string, List<string>> contentList = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
    {
        { "en-US",new List<string> (new string[] { "Dummy text 01","Dummy text 02"}) },
        { "es-ES",new List<string> (new string[] { "Texto ficticio 01", "Texto ficticio 02"}) }
    };
    string inputFile = @"C:\{username}\Desktop\Valentines_Day.xlsx";
    string sheetName = "Copy";

    writeExcelService.WriteValueToCell(inputFile, sheetName, contentList);
}
```

**WriteValueToCell method:**

```
char columnName = 'I';
        uint rowNumber = 1;
        foreach (var keys in contentList.Keys)
        {
            foreach (var value in contentList.Where(v => v.Key == keys).SelectMany(v => v.Value))
            {
                string cellAddress = String.Concat(columnName, rowNumber);
                this.Write(filepath, sheetName, value, cellAddress, rowNumber);
                int tempColumn = (int)columnName;
                columnName = (char)++tempColumn;
            }
            columnName = 'I';
            ++rowNumber;
        }
```

**Write method:**

```
private void Write(string filepath, string sheetName, string value, string cellAddress,uint rowNumber)
{
    // Create a spreadsheet document by supplying the filepath.
    // By default, AutoSave = true, Editable = true, and Type = xlsx.
    using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(filepath, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
    {
        //writeExcelService.WriteValueToCell(outputFilePath, sheetName, cellAddress, value.Value);
        // Add a WorkbookPart to the document.
        WorkbookPart workbookpart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart();
        workbookpart.Workbook = new Workbook();

        // Add a WorksheetPart to the WorkbookPart.
        WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookpart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
        worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());

        // Add Sheets to the Workbook.
        Sheets sheets = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());

        // Append a new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.
        Sheet sheet = new Sheet() { Id = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart), SheetId = 1, Name = sheetName };
        sheets.Append(sheet);

        // Get the sheetData cell table.
        SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();

        // Add a row to the cell table.
        Row row;
        row = new Row() { RowIndex = rowNumber };
        sheetData.Append(row);

        // In the new row, find the column location to insert a cell.
        Cell refCell = null;
        foreach (Cell cell in row.Elements<Cell>())
        {
            if (string.Compare(cell.CellReference.Value, cellAddress, true) > 0)
            {
                refCell = cell;
                break;
            }
        }

        // Add the cell to the cell table.
        Cell newCell = new Cell() { CellReference = cellAddress };
        row.InsertBefore(newCell, refCell);

        // Set the cell value to be a numeric value.
        newCell.CellValue = new CellValue(value);
        newCell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.Number);
    }
}
```

> My problem is:

My code executes but once the result file is opened, It prompts window as I posted above, and the file is empty.If I debug the code to insert list of contents one by one, it can be written correctly to Cells `I2` or `J2`. Since my code creates `SpreadsheetDocument` for each list content, therefore I have changed the `SpreadsheetDocument` creation approach in the code below:

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = File.Exists(filePath) ?
SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filepath, true) : 
SpreadsheetDocument.Create(filepath, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
   {

   }
```

But I am getting exception

> Only one instance of the type is allowed for this parent.

Anyone can help me on this?

Appreciate it in advance.

Comment: You want to insert text right? Then why is this line in your code: `newCell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.Number);`?

Comment: @FortyTwo I got a mistake with my code. I modified the algorithm and passed the row number as parameter instead of hard code it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out the solution myself. I have passed the list of string contents and write them all to corresponding Cells then closed the `SpreadSheetDocument`. In this way `SpreadSheetDocument` can be created once. Working code is below:

```
public void WriteValueToCell(string filepath, string sheetName, Dictionary<string, List<string>> contentList)
{
    // Create a spreadsheet document by supplying the filepath.
    // By default, AutoSave = true, Editable = true, and Type = xlsx.
    using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(filepath, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook, true))
    {
        // Add a WorkbookPart to the document.
        WorkbookPart workbookpart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart();
        workbookpart.Workbook = new Workbook();

        //Add a WorkbookStylesPart to the workbookpart
        WorkbookStylesPart stylesPart = workbookpart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>();
        stylesPart.Stylesheet = new Stylesheet();

        // Add a WorksheetPart to the WorkbookPart.
        WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookpart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
        worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());

        // Add Sheets to the Workbook.
        Sheets sheets = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());

        // Append a new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.
        Sheet sheet = new Sheet() { Id = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart), SheetId = 1, Name = sheetName };
        sheets.Append(sheet);

        // Get the sheetData cell table.
        SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();

        char columnName = 'I';
        uint rowNumber = 1;
        foreach (var keys in contentList.Keys)
        {
            foreach (var value in contentList.Where(v => v.Key == keys).SelectMany(v => v.Value))
            {
                string cellAddress = String.Concat(columnName, rowNumber);
                // Add a row to the cell table.
                Row row;
                row = new Row() { RowIndex = rowNumber };
                sheetData.Append(row);

                // In the new row, find the column location to insert a cell.
                Cell refCell = null;
                foreach (Cell cell in row.Elements<Cell>())
                {
                    if (string.Compare(cell.CellReference.Value, cellAddress, true) > 0)
                    {
                        refCell = cell;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                // Add the cell to the cell table.
                Cell newCell = new Cell() { CellReference = cellAddress };
                row.InsertBefore(newCell, refCell);
                // Set the cell value to be a numeric value.
                newCell.CellValue = new CellValue(value);
                newCell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String);

                int tempColumn = (int)columnName;
                columnName = (char)++tempColumn;
            }
            columnName = 'I';
            ++rowNumber;
        }
    }
}
```

Main method:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    WriteExcelService writeExcelService = new WriteExcelService();
    Dictionary<string, List<string>> contentList = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
    {
        { "en-US",new List<string> (new string[] { "Dummy text 01","Dummy text 02"}) },
        { "es-ES",new List<string> (new string[] { "Texto ficticio 01", "Texto ficticio 02"}) }
    };
    string inputFile = @"C:\{username}\Desktop\Valentines_Day.xlsx";
    string sheetName = "Copy";

    writeExcelService.WriteValueToCell(inputFile, sheetName, contentList);
}
```

Comment: This does not answer your own question! You ask about inserting into cell and answer about `SpreadSheetDocument` being created once? And then proxy up your answer?

Comment: Using blocks ensure `spreadsheetDocument ` is created only once. You cannot have multiple files of the same name. Can you?

Comment: It does. I used to put the Cell text writing process into foreach loop. So I have changed my algorithm to process text writing part of all Cells inside Using statement since I have encountered SpreadSheetDocument creation issue. Now the code creates SpreadSheetDocument once，fill up all expected Cells with corresponding strings and close the document. I have achieved what I want. Just have changed the way I used to think.

Comment: What do you mean `SpreadSheetDocument ` is created once? It can be created only once!! I shall repeat: MULTIPLE FILES CANNOT BE OF THE SAME NAME!

Comment: I have added the main method in my answer. Code result tells you everything.

Answer (score 3):

Strings in excel are saved under a *sharedStringTable*. When inserting a string it is important to add the string or reference the string from the *sharedStringTable*. Also, you need to provide the correct `DataType` for a cell. In your code, you are inserting all values as a number:

```
// Set the cell value to be a numeric value.
newCell.CellValue = new CellValue(value);
newCell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.Number);
```

To insert a string I would recommend using the following method after you have created a new cell:

```
private SpreadsheetDocument _spreadSheet;
private WorksheetPart _worksheetPart;
..
..
private void UpdateCell(Cell cell, DataTypes type, string text)
{
    if (type == DataTypes.String)
    {
        cell.DataType = CellValues.SharedString;

        if (!_spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>().Any())
        {
            _spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<SharedStringTablePart>();
        }

        var sharedStringTablePart = _spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>().First();
        if (sharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable == null)
        {
            sharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable = new SharedStringTable();
        }
        //Iterate through shared string table to check if the value is already present.
        foreach (SharedStringItem ssItem in sharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable.Elements<SharedStringItem>())
        {
            if (ssItem.InnerText == text)
            {
                cell.CellValue = new CellValue(ssItem.ElementsBefore().Count().ToString());
                return;
            }
        }
        // The text does not exist in the part. Create the SharedStringItem.
        var item = sharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable.AppendChild(new SharedStringItem(new Text(text)));
        cell.CellValue = new CellValue(item.ElementsBefore().Count().ToString());
    }
    else if (type == DataTypes.Number)
    {
        cell.CellValue = new CellValue(text);
        cell.DataType = CellValues.Number;
    }
    else if (type == DataTypes.DateTime)
    {

        cell.DataType = CellValues.Number;
        cell.StyleIndex = Convert.ToUInt32(_dateStyleIndex);

        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse(text);
        double oaValue = dateTime.ToOADate();
        cell.CellValue = new CellValue(oaValue.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }
    _worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
}
```

Comment: My code writes the content to the Cell even if the `DataType` is number, I have changed the type to `SharedString` anyway. But now the problem is my code creates new instance of `SpreadsheetDocument` to write content to each Cell. I have added a `File.Exists(filePath)` check but it still creates the Excel file every time. I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: You are probably overlooking something small. Maybe separate the logic with if blocks rather than using a ternary operator. Once you find your bug you can revert back to using ternary operator.

Comment: I have tried `if..else` statement instead ternary operator, result is the same as ternary operator.

Comment: Where does it create the new file? What is the name of the new file?

Comment: It creates the new file in the `using` statement. You may check my Main method for the file name. I have a better idea how to fix the problem.I will post my own answer right quick. Thanks for your afford.